# SyntaxError:invalid syntax

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run server in terminal but it returns a syntax Error, am using Django

This is the command response

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 22
    '/' if settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is not None force_text(settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME)
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

'/' if settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is not None force_text(settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME)
```

Comment: Have you edited that `__init__.py`? There should be a line break there. Don't edit Django's own code.

Comment: `else` is missing actually. Which means you've edited the file inside django.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to use `else`.

Change this:

```
'/' if settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is not None force_text(settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME)
```

To this:

```
'/' if settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is not None else force_text(settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME)
```

Comment: That might be correct but OP should never have edited files from the django package in the first place, so the better answer would be to tell OP to reinstall django, to make sure all files are original.

Comment: sure this helped